# SQL for selecting YTD active member by month

Tags: sql, count, ssms, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I need some help in writing a query which will return the distinct count of memberid who are active YTD and by each month

i.e.

202201 - distinct memberid who are active in 202201

202202 - distinct memberid who are active between 202201 - 202202

202203 - distinct memberid who are active between 202201 - 202203

the data structure are similar to below.

| memberid | yearmonth | activestatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202201 | Y |
| 1 | 202202 | Y |
| 1 | 202203 | N |
| 2 | 202201 | N |
| 2 | 202202 | N |
| 2 | 202203 | Y |
| 3 | 202201 | N |
| 3 | 202202 | Y |
| 3 | 202203 | Y |

Thanks you.

Expected:

| yearmonth | active_status |
| --- | --- |
| 202201 | 1 |
| 202202 | 2 |
| 202203 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can express the logic neatly with two levels of aggregation. This might be more efficient than filtering with `row_number()`:

```
select yearmonth, sum(count(*)) over(order by yearmonth) running_cnt
from (
    select min(yearmonth) yearmonth from mytable where activestatus = 'Y' group by memberid
) t
group by yearmonth
```

This first gets the earliest active date per member, and then aggregates and computes the running sum.

In a normal situation you would also have a calendar table that holds all possible `yearmonth` values, and you would use it like so:

```
select c.yearmonth, sum(count(t.yearmonth)) over(order c.by yearmonth) running_cnt
from calendar c
left join (
    select min(yearmonth) yearmonth from mytable where activestatus = 'Y' group by memberid
) t on t.yearmonth = c.yearmonth 
group by c.yearmonth
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works when I select one specific year (i.e. 2022 in the calendar table), and it won't work if I have multiple years run at the same time, as it calculated the running value from the earliest yearmonth, but I think this should be good as I would have just change it by years.

Answer (score 0):

We're looking for a distinct running count. We can achieve it by using `row_number()` and `count()`.

```
select distinct yearmonth                 
      ,count(rn) over(order by yearmonth) as distinct_running_count
from
(
select *
      ,case when row_number() over(partition by memberid order by yearmonth) = 1 then 1 end as rn
from   t
where  activestatus = 'Y'
) t
```

| yearmonth | distinct_running_count |
| --- | --- |
| 202201 | 1 |
| 202202 | 2 |
| 202203 | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7FnjjIT2)